# VBA - Continuous overwriting

Tags: excel, vba

There is a file with several tables ("Pages" = Table 1, Table 2, etc.). The "Customer_ID" column appears repeatedly within these tables. In total, there are over 1,000 customer IDs, which can also appear repeatedly in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Changing Unique ID (Dictionary)

- In the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`), loops through each cell in column `A` of each worksheet whose name is starting with `wsBaseName`, and changes its value with a unique ID that consists of `idBaseName` and a corresponding number. The number is incremented for each initial unique value.

```vb
Option Explicit
  
Sub ChangeID()
   
    Const wsBaseName As String = "Tabelle"
    Const idBaseName As String = "ABC"
       
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' ignore case of 'idBaseName'
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim cCell As Range
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ' Only if the worksheet name starts with 'wsBaseName'
        ' and ignoring case ('TaBeLlE = Tabelle').
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, wsBaseName, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If lRow > 1 Then ' check if any id's
                Set rg = ws.Range("A2:A" & lRow)
                For Each cCell In rg.Cells
                    Key = CStr(cCell.Value)
                    If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
                        n = n + 1
                        dict.Add Key, idBaseName & n
                    End If
                    cCell.Value = dict(Key)
                Next cCell
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    
    MsgBox "Done.", vbInformation, "Change ID"
   
End Sub
```

### EDIT

- The following is assuming that the data in all the relevant worksheets start in the same row (`HeaderRow`).
- The functionality of using different headers has been implemented (`ColNamesList`).
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Sub ChangeIDPart2()
   
    Const wsBaseName As String = "Tabelle"
    Const idBaseName As String = "ABC"
    Const ColNamesList As String = "customer_id,CID" ' add more
    Const HeaderRow As Long = 1
       
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim fRow As Long: fRow = HeaderRow + 1
    
    Dim ColNames() As String: ColNames = Split(ColNamesList, ",")
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(ColNames)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' ignore case of 'idBaseName'
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet ' Current Worksheet
    Dim rrg As Range ' Entire Row of Headers
    Dim rg As Range ' ID Column Range
    Dim cCell As Range ' Current Cell in ID Column Range
    Dim cIndex As Variant ' Current ID Column (could be an error value)
    Dim Key As Variant ' Current ID (string)
    Dim lRow As Long ' ID Column Last Non-Empty (Not Hidden) Row
    Dim n As Long ' New ID Incrementer
    Dim i As Long ' Column Names (Titles, Headers) Counter
    Dim foundHeader As Boolean ' Found Header Boolean
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ' Only if the worksheet name starts with 'wsBaseName'
        ' and ignoring case ('TaBeLlE = Tabelle').
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, wsBaseName, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            Set rrg = ws.Rows(HeaderRow)
            For i = 0 To cUpper
                cIndex = Application.Match(ColNames(i), rrg, 0)
                If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
                    foundHeader = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            If foundHeader Then
                foundHeader = False ' reset
                lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, cIndex).End(xlUp).Row
                If lRow > 1 Then ' check if any id's
                    Set rg = ws.Range(ws.Cells(fRow, cIndex), _
                        ws.Cells(lRow, cIndex))
                    For Each cCell In rg.Cells
                        Key = CStr(cCell.Value)
                        If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
                            n = n + 1
                            dict.Add Key, idBaseName & n
                        End If
                        cCell.Value = dict(Key)
                    Next cCell
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    
    MsgBox "Done.", vbInformation, "Change ID Part 2"
   
End Sub
```

Comment: What if the Customer_ID isn't always in Row "A" and can have a different name e.g. "CID"?
And thr worksheets have different names.

Comment: 2. You will have to write the possible column names to a data structure (e.g. an array) and loop through it. 1. It's an easy fix but you haven't described your data most accurately. Are the tables `Excel Tables`? If not, do they always start in `A1`? If they are, are there more tables than one per worksheet? Be more specific. You will have to find the column of the appropriate header and do the `End(xlUp)` there for each worksheet.

Comment: I added a new figure, hope it will help.
Yes, they are Excel Tables. The Customer_ID appears on several worksheets, but only one time per worksheet. The two Rows on the right from the Customer_ID (Those without header) are not really there, but how the row customer_ID should look like (ABC1,...)

Comment: I've added a new version.

Comment: It says "Done" but nothing changed.

Comment: Your worksheets are not called `TabelleX` in the new images so you should remove the 'restriction to those worksheets', i.e. delete the line `If InStr(1, ws.Name, wsBaseName, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then` and the corresponding `End If`. Also, then you don't need the line `Const wsBaseName As String = "Tabelle"` anymore.

Comment: Okay I came a step further. Now it worked on all the Data which is listed in Row "A". Tried some things out, but couldn't edit the other ones. Also when I leave first Columns in Row "A" empty which were followed by the IDs, the empty ones were filled in with Data after using the Code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a formula like`="ABC" & A:A` in column B for example. Then turn those formulas it into values using `Range("B:B").Value = Range("B:B").Value` and you can delete column A. If you do that in each sheet you got your replacement very easily:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Dim RangeIDs As Range
    Set RangeIDs = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))  ' ID data without header

    ' write formula next to ID data into column B
    RangeIDs.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Formula = "=""ABC"" & A:A"

    ' turn formula into values
    With RangeIDs.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    ' delete ID Data
    RangeIDs.Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
Next ws
```