# Overwrite & Distribute Values

Tags: excel, vba

There are around 1000 different "customer_ids" in total. These can also occur several times in the file on several worksheets.
The "customer_id" data records should be automatically overwritten with a new name. The designation represents a format consisting of a fixed sequence of letters + a consecutive, ascending number -> ABC1, ABC2, ..., ABCn. See figure above left.

The name of the row-header and its position can be different in the worksheets. This means that the "customer_id" can also be found as "cust_id" in columns other than "A". See figures.

The recurring customer_id's should have the same name on all worksheets, see figures.

Comment: Can you edit your question and clearly explain (**in words**) what you try accomplishing? I could understand the existing situation, but I am not sure that I could understand which to be the processing result... Your second code put the ID like a dictionary key, adding its value by concatenation of "ABC" with a incremented Long variable and changes the existing ID with that key value. Isn't it what you try accomplishing? If yes, your second code looks to do it. Where is that code problem? Does it raise an error? If yes, what error and on which row? If not, where the problem is, please...

Comment: It looks like you are replacing always in column A with the name of the customer_id. Use a dictionary.

Comment: In the second code is a comment: "Only if the worksheet name starts with 'wsBaseName'", but your code does not implement this requirement...

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, it's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. Problem is that the values were not changed with the second code. I deleted the statement, maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68065384/vba-continuous-overwriting

Comment: What do you mean by deleting "the statement"? Are you referring to the comment I mentioned above? Try moving the code line `Key = CStr(cCell.Value)` above `For Each cCell In rg.Cells`... In this way `cCell.Value = dict(Key)` uses an updated `Key` value.

Comment: In the previous thread I had a different table. There was a statement called: Const wsBaseName As String = "Tabelle". So VBasic2008 told me to delete it. I forgot to delete the comment in the code too.
If you follow the comments in the link aboce you know what I mean.

Comment: Did you moved the code line as I recommended in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes, it says "done" but the values did not change. @FaneDuru

Comment: Pleaase, Insert the line `Debug.Print ws.Name, foundHeader, Key:Stop` above `For Each cCell In rg.Cells`. What does it return in Immediate window (Ctrl + G, being in VBE)? Note it and press F5 to run the code for the next sheet...

Comment: It returns nothing in the immediate windows. When I run the code it says again "done" without changes. @FaneDuru

Comment: @FaneDuru
Ok now it says "Compilation Error, Variable not declared" and marks "foundHeader".

Comment: This line is wrong: `ColNames = Split(ColNamesList, ",")`. It should be `ColNames = Split(ColNamesList, ", ")`. A space after comma. Or change the constant as: `"cid,customer_id,ids,cust_id"`  instead of `"cid, customer_id, ids, cust_id"`. But change only one of them... :)

Comment: This is not possible. Your code has `Dim foundHeader As Boolean`. Only if you did not comment or delete it by mistake... Or used something else. Maybe `faundHeader` or something else similar...

Comment: @FaneDuru It worked on worksheet 1&2 but not on 3&4.

Comment: Do these 3&4 have the header on the first row?

Comment: @FaneDuru No they haven't. You can see it in the figures 3&4.

Comment: I can see the header on the first row **in all sheets**.  Anyhow, if not on the first row, **on which row is the header**?

Comment: @FaneDuru In figure three it appears in row "B" and starts in the column 5. In figure 4 it appears in row "D" and starts with columns 3.

Comment: Do you know what **a row** is, no offence? You are enumerating columns...

Comment: My mistake. I talked about rows and ment columns.

Comment: Okay, so yes they have the header in the first row but different columns.

Comment: If they have the header in the first row, this can only mean that the spelling of the headers in discussion are wrongly spelled. Maybe "cid ", or " cid" ore some other not characters not visible (spaces, usually)... Please edit each such cell and check it against extra spaces. You can also try changing `cIndex = Application.Match(ColNames(i), rrg, 0)` with `cIndex = Application.Match(Trim(ColNames(i)), rrg, 0)`.

Comment: It is late in my country and I must go to bed. If you cannot solve it following the above suggestions, I will try helping you tomorrow...

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks.
I tried some things out and it worked. I used it on the original table. Here is the issue that the Row-Header appears not on the first row in all sheets.

Comment: I asked you about that... I already prepared a piece of code to replace part of yours, to search for other rows, in case of a `False` `foundHeader` searching in the first row. If you like me to post it, I can do it...

Comment: @FaneDuru - That would be great. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next (working) solution:

**Edited**:

Please, try the next version (using arrays) which should be much faster:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeIDPart2()
   
    Const idBaseName As String = "ABC"
    Const ColNamesList As String = "customer_id,cust_id" ' add more
    Const HeaderRow As Long = 1
       
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim fRow As Long: fRow = HeaderRow + 1
    
    Dim ColNames() As String: ColNames = Split(ColNamesList, ",")
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(ColNames)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' ignore case of 'idBaseName'
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet ' Current Worksheet
    Dim rrg As Range ' Entire Row of Headers
    Dim arr As Variant ' ID Column Range array (changed...)
    Dim cCell As Range ' Current Cell in ID Column Range
    Dim cIndex As Variant ' Current ID Column (could be an error value)
    Dim Key As Variant ' Current ID (string)
    Dim lRow As Long ' ID Column Last Non-Empty (Not Hidden) Row
    Dim n As Long ' New ID Incrementer
    Dim i As Long ' Column Names (Titles, Headers) Counter
    Dim foundHeader As Boolean ' Found Header Boolean
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            fRow = HeaderRow + 1
            Set rrg = ws.Rows(HeaderRow)
            For i = 0 To cUpper
                cIndex = Application.Match(ColNames(i), rrg, 0)
                If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
                    foundHeader = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            If Not foundHeader Then
                Dim k As Long
                For k = 1 To 5
                    Set rrg = ws.Rows(HeaderRow + k)
                    For i = 0 To cUpper
                        cIndex = Application.Match(ColNames(i), rrg, 0)
                        If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
                            fRow = rrg.row + 1
                            foundHeader = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next i
                    If foundHeader Then Exit For
                Next k
            End If
            If Not foundHeader Then MsgBox "In sheet " & ws.Name & _
                                 " an appropriate header could not be found in first 6 rows..."
            If foundHeader Then
                foundHeader = False ' reset
                lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, cIndex).End(xlUp).Row
                If lRow > 1 Then   ' check if any id's
                    arr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(fRow, cIndex), _
                                                ws.Cells(lRow, cIndex)).Value 'put the range in array (to iterate faster)
                    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
                        Key = CStr(arr(i, 1))
                        If Key <> "" Then
                            If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
                                n = n + 1
                                dict.Add Key, idBaseName & n
                            End If
                            arr(i, 1) = dict(Key)
                        End If
                    Next i
                    ws.Range(ws.Cells(fRow, cIndex), _
                                    ws.Cells(lRow, cIndex)).Value = arr 'drop back in the range the processed array
                End If
            End If
    Next ws
    
    MsgBox "Done.", vbInformation, "Change ID Part 2"
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback. I am curious how much it takes. Theoretically, it should be obviously faster.

Comment: "In sheet cid, customer_id, ids, cust_id  an appropriate header could not be found in first 6 rows..."
I will edit the code in my question how it looks like now.

Comment: @Eren Jaeger Please, only show how `ColNamesList ` constant has been built...

Comment: @Eren Jaeger If not something confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion?

Comment: I can share the example workbook. It is the same in structure.
Where can I share it?

Comment: @Eren Jaeger you can use my personal mail (from my user profile) or a transfer site. [This one](https://easyupload.io/) is free and easy to be used... If you will send me by mail, please confirm it. Otherwise, it will go on Spam...

Comment: @Eren Jaeger I was waiting to receive a xlsm file having the code you use... Now you deleted your initial code (in the question, I mean) and did not understand what 'existing code...' should mean... Do you think, I memorized the code and now I can reproduce it? :) I can do a different one, but why not using a working version only needing something to be changed? I will try extracting it from the editing history, if it kept it.

Comment: @Eren Jaeger [Here](https://easyupload.io/4xz4ey), the working solutions. It uses the above (updated) code. The previous one used to have a typo: `founheader` instead of `foundHeader`. Receiving that error this only meant that you do not have `Option Explicit` on top of the module. I alo excepted the empty cells to receive a code in the dictionary and the cell... Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: It took around 7hours to tun the code but it worked! Thanks, you're the man!

Comment: @Eren Jaeger What to be tuned? I sent you back a working code. Didn't you use the above code? I really cannot understand what was to be changed/adapted... I tested it on the workbook you sent and I sent it back. Can you explain what was necessary to be adapted? Anyhow, we here, when somebody help us solving our problem, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Comment: No no, the code was just perfect! I just wanted to let you know it took 7hours to run the code on the original table, because it is much larger than the example I sent you. But it worked absolutely perfect!

Comment: Can I give you somewhere something like a 5-Star rating?

Comment: @Eren Jaeger Nope... Not necessary, anyhow. Glad I could help!

Comment: Hey there, I just wanted to ask if it's possible to run the code faster? It rewrote over 40.000 customer_ids correctly, but it took over 6 hours to finish.

Comment: @Eren Jaeger OK. I will try preparing a version using arrays instead of ranges, which should be faster.

Comment: @Eren Jaeger Edited the code and placed the new (faster, I hope) version. Please, test this version (**after Edit:**) and send some feedback.

Comment: Thank you very much, it took just a few seconds :D

Comment: I've noticed that, the code was used on / has overwritten, the row header "cust_id" with "ABC10".

Comment: This can happen only if `fRow` is wrongly defined, I think. This should not be connected to the updated code. Probably, this is happening in the sheets where the headers row is not 1. It should be redefined in the loop of searching for the new row with headers.

Comment: Yes excactly, the row header starts here at 2.

Comment: @Eren Jaeger I adapted the code, inserting `fRow = rrg + 1` just above the code line `foundHeader = True` in the new sequence, searching from another header row, if not find in the initial one... Please, test this new version and send some feedback.

Comment: Run-time error '13': Type mismatch. The values of "customer_id" were changed, but not the values of "cust_id".

Comment: @Eren Jaeger Ups... I missed  '.Row` from the code line I inserted. It should be `fRow = rrg.row + 1`. I adapted the code. Not tested and at the first glance, I did not observed that `rrg` is a range. I thought it is a Long variable, keeping the row index...

Comment: Now some values in "customer_id" & "cust_id" are not overwritten. Probably because the row headers are starting differently from worksheet to worksheet. For example: On Worksheet A "customer_id" starts at 1, but in Worksheet B in 3. Same goes for "cust_id"

Comment: Then, `fRow ` should be reinitialized (it remains as it has been calculated for the previous iterated sheet) on each iteration. Try inserting `fRow = HeaderRow + 1` just after `For Each ws In wb.Worksheets`.

Comment: @Eren Jaeger OK. I will adapt the code and delete first slow code variant... Did it.